# How to retrieve full referring URL in Sinatra?

Tags: javascript, ruby, header, sinatra, http-referer

My app is written in Ruby on a Sinatra framework. One of the functions in my app displays javascript code. That javascript code is called by remote websites. In Ruby, I need to know the full URL of the remote website calling the javascript code so that I can make changes to the javascript code. I have tried retrieving the `request.referrer` and `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]` but they only seem to retrieve the schema and domain of the referring domain. How do I get the full referring URL?

For reference, here is the Sinatra file that I am using to test this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get %r{/test} do
    debug = {:referrer => request.referrer, :http_referer => request.env["HTTP_REFERER"], :path_info => request.path_info, :query_string => request.query_string, :host => request.host, :url => request.url, :path => request.path}
    STDERR.puts debug.inspect
    erb "test"
end
```

If this Sinatra file was hosted at http://www.server.com, you should be able to access this function by going to http://www.server.com/test

Then, if there was a remote website at http://www.remote.com/url-with-test-code.html with the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://www.server.com/test">
test
</body>
</html>
```

For this example, this is the results I am seeing:

{:referrer=>"https://www.remote.com/", :http_referer=>"https://www.remote.com/", :path_info=>"/test", :query_string=>"", :host=>"www.server.com", :url=>"https://www.server.com/test", :path=>"/test"}

But I would expect the "referrer" key to be "https://www.remote.com/url-with-test-code.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the browser's referrer policy. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64777573/1698908) gives more detail:

> Many browsers have started to default to a stricter referrer policy
> (`strict-origin-when-cross-origin`) when making a cross-domain request
> instead of the old default (`no-referrer-when-downgrade`). This will
> most often result in truncated urls, but occasionally means that the
> referrer will not be set at all (`no-referrer`).